# Matlab creates empty file when compiled and deployed

Tags: matlab

Im developing a matlab app that generates a config.ini file during its run. 
when i run the code from with in matlab it works fine and the ini files are generated as expected. 
when i compile the code, using matlab compiler (mcc) and run it as an executable it generates an empty config ini. 
any idea why the different output compiled vs. not-compiled?

This is the code that does the printing

```
fid = fopen(file_name, 'w');

if (fid ~= -1)
    str = obj.ToString();
    fprintf(fid, '%s', str);

    fclose(fid);
    status = true;
else
    status = false;
    return;
end
```

system is Ubuntu 12.04, Matlab 2015b
Thanks

Resolved - problem was that in order to generate the new config i read an empty config templete. running from within matlab i only need to provide file name (as its already on the build path) , when deployed i need to provide full path of the template config...so file was generated empty because there was no string loaded from the template...

Comment: My guess is that it's a permissions issue with where it's trying to write the file so `fid` is going to be `-1`. I'm not sure what `file_name` is but maybe ensure that it is within a user's directory that they can write to?

Comment: Also what is `obj`? Is that a java object?

Comment: Hi. obj is a matlab obj. its the INI object that holds all the config parameters.

Comment: Not sure its permissions issue since i have another function in the same app that writes a log file... that log file is being written both when running from the editor and running the compiled version of it...